# Stop execution of all methods from child method

Tags: c#, methods, return

I am working with a few methods that are called from within other methods, but need to stop processing both methods if an event occurs in the one called from the parent. An example of what I am doing in code would be this:

```
private void parentMethod()
{
   //Do work here
   childMethod();
   //Do more work here
}
private void childMethod()
{
//Do work (not child labor)

using (var form = new choice(myList))
    {
        var result = form.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int val = form.listIndex;//values preserved after close
            //Do something here with these values
            string server = myList2[val - 1];
            MyList.Clear();
            MyList.Add(server);
        }
        else
        {
            Exception e = new Exception("Dialog force closed.",null);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

So as you can see here, I tried creating an exception to throw; however, because there are number of other methods getting called from the parent method which also can throw exceptions, but can allow the rest of the code to execute, and the parent method in this example is being called from another method that needs to be stopped as well, how do you stop the execution of multiple methods from within a child method, other that doing `Application.Close()`?

Comment: I would use a parameter so private void childMethod() is private int childMethod()  and set return value = 1 if it makes it through and 0 if it has an error then test that before further processing.  I did not downtick you.

Comment: @Missy why not just return a boolean at that point?

Comment: That's a fine idea, too.

Comment: Also, you should not be throwing exceptions around op, unless you have a really good reason to. Just do as missy said, and check for a true/false condition when executing your code.

Comment: There is no property or function to call in C# that would do that then? This is quite tedious to do, especially when you have 3-4 child methods being called from inside one another. EDIT* Not saying its a bad idea, but if there was a more graceful way of doing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more specific in your exception catching.  In general, a bare `catch` is bad practice anywhere except the very top level, as is `catch (Exception e)` or similar.  You should determine which exceptions a method can throw, and then *only* catch those.  Other exceptions will then be passed back up the call stack.

For instance, if you have a method `A()` that might throw an `InvalidOperationException`, `B()` that might throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` or `ArgumentNullException`, and `C()` that might throw an `AccessViolationException`, your code should look like

```
public int Main()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            A()
        }
        catch(InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            //handle
        }

        try
        {
            B()
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
        {
            //handle
        }
        catch(ArgumentNullException e)
        {
            //handle
        }

        try
        {
            C()
        }
        catch(AccessViolationException e)
        {
            //handle
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //handle all other exceptions
    }
}
```

Now, if any method out of `A`,`B`, and `C` throws an exception you're not expecting, it will be handled by the final `catch` block.

If you really must have an exception that can only be handled at the top level, it might be a good idea to create your own Exception class:

```
 class MyApplicationException : Exception { }
```

Then, as long as you *never* use `catch (Exception)` anywhere other than at the top level, you will be fine.

Comment: @Termonator145 yes, as long as every level is specific in its catches.